# Will i ever be able to see pokemon in AR mode on pokemon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

What I really want to know is can this be something they can fix in the future with an update? Will I be able to see Pokemon in the future on my phone even if it doesn't have a gyroscope or will I just have to get a new phone? And does anyone know when the next update will come?

Comment: Also, Niantic has not released any information on if they will release an update for the AR mode. We have no way of knowing if or when they will fix this

Answer (score 3):

Without a gyroscope, your phone will not be capable of AR regardless of updates to the game.